# What to add to link to make page load with specific tab selected

Tags: html, angularjs, hyperlink, angular-ui-bootstrap

### Add script to link

I'm trying to load specific page content.
For this i need that page will be open with Rawdata [tab](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!tabs) instead of Summary.
What i need to add to the link to ensure that page will load with "Rawdata"

[image: How the page loaded]

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"
    ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}"
    ng-transclude="">
  <li class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope active"
      data-select="tabChanged('Summary')"
      data-heading="Summary" data-index="'Summary'"
      data-uib-tab=""
      ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]">
    <a class="nav-link ng-binding" href="" ng-click="select($event)"
       uib-tab-heading-transclude="">Summary</a>
  </li>
  <li class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" data-select="tabChanged('Pareto')" data-heading="Pareto" data-index="'Pareto'" data-uib-tab="" ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]">
    <a class="nav-link ng-binding" href="" ng-click="select($event)" uib-tab-heading-transclude="">Pareto</a>
  </li>
  <li class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"
      data-select="tabChanged('RawData')" data-heading="Rawdata"
      data-index="'RawData'" data-uib-tab=""
      ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]">
    <a class="nav-link ng-binding" href=""
       ng-click="select($event)" uib-tab-heading-transclude="">Rawdata</a>
  </li>
  <li class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" data-select="tabChanged('SummaryTable')" data-heading="Waiting Hours" data-index="'SummaryTable'" data-uib-tab="" ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]">
    <a class="nav-link ng-binding" href="" ng-click="select($event)" uib-tab-heading-transclude="">Waiting Hours</a>
  </li>
  <li class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" data-select="tabChanged('Analysis')" data-heading="Analysis" data-index="'Analysis'" data-uib-tab="" ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]">
    <a class="nav-link ng-binding" href="" ng-click="select($event)" uib-tab-heading-transclude="">Analysis</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to show the template before it is compiled by the AngularJS framework. Look for a `<uib-tabset>` element. It will show the scope variable that controls the selection of the tab.

For more information, see

- [Angular-UI-Bootstrap `tabs` Directive Reference and Demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!tabs)